# Angular 1: Add new ID to newly created objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form with only 1 input field. For each input a new object is created.This is my method for adding new objects. I am looking for Angular way to add IDs to these objects, what would you suggest?

```
$scope.addToDoItem = function(){
  var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
  var newToDoItem = {
    "id" : // id should be generated here
    "content" : $scope.toDoItem,
    "createdAt" : Date.now()
  }
  toDoItems.push(newToDoItem);
  ls.set("toDoData", toDoItems);
  $scope.toDoItem = "";
};
```

The view:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="toDoItem">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="addToDoItem()">
  </form>
```

Comment: so, where is problem?

Comment: @Grundy I can't figure out what is Angular way to generate ID for objects

Comment: but what id you want? just number: 1,2,3,4 etc?

Comment: @Grundy Yes that is what I want.

Comment: There's no "Angualar way" in this particular case. However, your way of doing isn't optimal in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is "angular way" of doing it.

However, currently you are using the milliseconds for `createdAt` value, so you can use the same value for Id as well. If you don't have application where new value can be added more frequently you will have your unique value:

```
var currentDate = Date.now();
var newToDoItem = {
    "id" : currentDate
    "content" : $scope.toDoItem,
    "createdAt" : currentDate
}
```

The downside is that the ID values will be large and they will not come in order. If you want values to be 1, 2, 3, etc, then you can create variable for maximum ID in your controller and use it to increase the value:

```
var maxId = 0;
//if you need to restore maxId you can use
//var maxId = $scope.toDoItems.reduce(function(max,cur){return Math.max(max,cur.id); },0);
$scope.addToDoItem = function(){
  var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
  maxId++;
  var newToDoItem = {
    "id" : maxId,
    "content" : $scope.toDoItem,
    "createdAt" : Date.now()
  }
  toDoItems.push(newToDoItem);
  ls.set("toDoData", toDoItems);
  $scope.toDoItem = "";
};
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same, I will wait a bit if someone comes with different solution, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Kunok I edited the answer with alternative approach

Comment: About your alternate solution. What happens if someone refreshes a website? maxId gets reset and newly created values wouldn't have unique ID's, right?

Comment: @Kunok, sure counter reset after refresh, but you can go over toDoItems array and get max id

Comment: @Grundy Would you please add that as edit to this answer so I accept it as an answer with 3  different  solutions?

Comment: @Kunok, just do instead `var maxId = 0;` something like `var maxId = $scope.toDoItems.reduce(function(max,cur){return Math.max(max,cur.id); },0);`

Comment: @Grundy Would you mind to suggest edit with this solution aswell, so others can easy find it in answers?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a random hash you could also do this

```
$scope.addToDoItem = function() {
var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
var newToDoItem = {
    "id": function randString() {
        var x = 32; // hashlength
        var s = "";
        while (s.length < x && x > 0) {
            var r = Math.random();
            s += (r < 0.1 ? Math.floor(r * 100) : String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(r * 26) + (r > 0.5 ? 97 : 65)));
        }
        return s;
    },
    "content": $scope.toDoItem,
    "createdAt": Date.now()
}
toDoItems.push(newToDoItem);
ls.set("toDoData", toDoItems);
$scope.toDoItem = "";
};
```